# How to use model.ckpt and inception v-3 to predict images?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, imagenet

Now I'm in front of the problem about inception v-3 and checkpoint data.
I have been tackling with updating inception-v3's checkpoint data by my images, reading the git page below and succeeded to make new checkpoint data.

> https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception

I thought at first just by little change of the code, I can use those checkpoint data to recognise new image datas like the below url.

> https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/image_recognition/index.html

I thought at first that "classify.py" or something reads the new check point datas and just by "python classify.py -image something.png", the program recognises the image data. But It doesn't....
I really need a help.
thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To have input .pb file, during training, import also tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph.as_graph_def(), 'path_to_folder', 'input_graph.pb',False)

If you have downloaded the inception v3 source code, in the inception_train.py, add the line I wrote above, under 
saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step=step). (Where you save the checkpoint/s)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

To use your checkpoints and model in something like the label_image example, you'll need to run the tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph script to convert your variables into constants stored inside the GraphDef. That's how we created the graph file used in that sample code, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But actually only outputs I got from re-train are checkpoint, model.ckpt and model.ckpt.meta datas. There is not even .pb datas to try fleeze_graph